# Trigger event on Individual Component Without triggering others with Shared Class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sliders.

The sliders are operated by arrows.

The sliders and arrows have the same class.

At the moment when one of the arrows on Slider A is pressed, BOTH slider A and slider B move.

Is it possible to click the arrow on slider A and only have slider A move WITHOUT changes classes or using ids.

Here is code for the sliders:

HTML:

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide on"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide on"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

.slide {
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.arrow-left {
    background: url('../images/arrowleft.svg');
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
}

.arrow-right {
    background: url('../images/arrowright.svg');
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
}

.on {
    height: 500px;
   min-width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
    $('.slider').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.arrow-left').on("click", function() {
        $('.slide').animate({
            left: "-=33%"
        })
        $('.on').next().addClass('on')
        $('.on').prev().removeClass('on')
    })

    $(this).find('.arrow-right').on("click", function() {
        $('.slide').animate({
            left: "+=33%"
        })
        $('.on').prev().addClass('on')
        $('.on').next().removeClass('on')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this, saving the jQuery element of the slider you are working on as a function local variable to restrict the class selections with `find`

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
    var _slider = $(this);
    
    _slider.find('.arrow-left').on("click", function() {
        _slider.find('.slide').animate({
            left: "-=33%"
        })
        _slider.find('.on').next().addClass('on')
        _slider.find('.on').prev().removeClass('on')
    })

    _slider.find('.arrow-right').on("click", function() {
        _slider.find('.slide').animate({
            left: "+=33%"
        })
        _slider.find('.on').prev().addClass('on')
        _slider.find('.on').next().removeClass('on')
    })
})
```

Not tested but it should work

NOTE: you should also be able to chain the `addClass` and `removeClass` too. Because once you added the class, the following line of code now selects 2 elements (with the one you just added the class on) and can lead to unexpected things. Chaining the calls should solve this. (EDIT: simpler version)

```
_slider.find('.on').removeClass('on').next().addClass('on')
```

Comment: I have edited the part to update the switching of the `on` class for a simpler version